# How I get specific row during query from two tables in Influx

Tags: database, influxdb, influxql

I tried to write a query to Influx Database in below example:

I have two tables:

```
table_1

id | value 
1  | 100
2  | 200

table_2

id | value 
1  | 900
2  | 800
```

I want to use one query to gets rows: id 1 and 2 from `table_1` and id 2 from `table_2`

In query:
`SELECT * FROM table_1, table_2 WHERE id=1 AND id=2`... I getting all data.

I tried:
`SELECT * FROM table_1, table_2 WHERE table_1.id=1 AND id=2`
... but it doesn't work.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used sub-queries eg.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM table_1 WHERE id='1' AND id='2'), (SELECT * FROM table_2 WHERE id='2') WHERE ...
```